# Is it possible to regain a "one time" spirit?

Tags: super-smash-bros-ultimate

Let's say you get a spirit from completing one of the challenges and you end up dismissing the spirit. Didn't happen to me, but I was just wondering, would the spirit be forever lost? Or does unlocking the spirit just add it to the regular rotation of spirits on the spirit board and shops?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All spirits can re-appear through New Game+ AND the Spirit Board, so don't fret if you've recycled one to make way for others.

Comment: Will the Spirit Board ever have event-specific spirits after the event (after having first collected the spirit during the event)? If not, then that might be one case where you do end up losing a spirit forever.

Comment: As of 2.0.0, all prior event-specific spirits (and the Pokemon Let's Go spirits) will now show up in the shop. This will probably not change in the future (showing up in the shop some time after being event-specific).